# Python integration with Gitlab

Tags: python, gitlab

I want to do a project that automatically copy a gitlab repository, change some variables in some files and push the changes in another gitlab repository.

I am thinking about a flask project, where the user can write the value of that variables in an HTML form. The original files are in a gitlab repository, using a script i can clone that repository, using sed this values where overwritten in new files in a new directory. The problem i encountered is with pushing the files to another repository. I cannot find the way to do it automatically with python.

Comment: Don't you know how that would be done in (pure) git or is your question specific to a Python library?

Comment: What exactly was the problem? Please share your code and errors as a [mcve]

Comment: By the way, assuming you're trying to make a template library. Look at cookiecutter rather than simple string replacing

Answer (score 1):

[GitPython](https://gitpython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html) is probably the package you are looking for - it nicely handles cloning, adding a new remote, and pushing.

Comment: For clarity, it should be able to be used within Flask (or any python web framework)

Comment: Yup, gitpython works as part of the backend of a flask app